# Iterate over dates and point locations to extract different data in Google Earth Engine: Append an imported table

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, feature-set

I am using the same code for my purpose in [Iterating over dates to extract precipitation in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388508/iterating-over-dates-to-extract-precipitation-in-google-earth-engine/401159?noredirect=1#comment654479_401159)

Here is a copy of my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fbenchamirouche%2Ffirst_code_ee%3Aabitibi_data_extract

I had a problem with the table exported in Gdrive. It is putting {} with all the data exported.

precipitations {prcp=0.0} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=0.6100000143051147} {prcp=0.3499999940395355} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=1.340000033378601} {prcp=1.8600000143051147} {prcp=5.059999942779541} {prcp=2.9200000762939453} {prcp=5.099999904632568} {prcp=5.579999923706055} {prcp=3.7200000286102295} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=0.0} {prcp=22.270000457763672} {prcp=14.640000343322754} {prcp=15.229999542236328} {prcp=10.880000114440918}

In the table metadata it says it is a dictionary object. How can I remove this curly brackets it the table cells?

Comment: The code doesn't exist in your link. You should do that again.